# SQL Pivot using count

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a table which has the following entries

```
ID | column   | value
------------------------
1  | status   | DONE
2  | status   | FAILED
1  | progress | Green
2  | progress | Red
```

i want the output as

```
ID | DONE | FAILED | GREEN | RED
1  | 1    | 0      | 1     | 0
2  | 0    | 1      | 0     | 1
```

Please let me know the query. I have tried pivot but not getting the results.

Comment: you should post some progress you have already done so we can help.

Comment: Why did you label SQL Server if you are actually using Oracle?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a standard pivot query solution which does not use SQL Server's built in `PIVOT` capability:

```
SELECT ID,
    SUM(CASE WHEN value = 'DONE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   AS DONE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN value = 'FAILED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FAILED,
    SUM(CASE WHEN value = 'Green' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS GREEN,
    SUM(CASE WHEN value = 'Red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)    AS RED
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: missing `FROM` clause

Comment: SELECT KEY_VALUE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN value = 'DONE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   AS 'DONE',
    SUM(CASE WHEN value = 'FAILED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'FAILED',
    SUM(CASE WHEN value = 'GREEN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 'GREEN',
    SUM(CASE WHEN value = 'RED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)    AS 'RED'
    FROM TABLE_NAME where METRIC_NAME='METRIC_NAME'
GROUP BY KEY_VALUE; This gives me error ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 56 Column: 58

Comment: This query looks OK to me.  Are you sure you copied it correctly?

Comment: Are you joking here?  You said you're using Oracle.

Comment: can any1 pls clarify, if im missing something?

Comment: My guess is that you have a typo in your query.  Update your original question with the query you have tried and maybe something will stand out at us.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM   atable 
PIVOT  (
           COUNT(column)
           FOR value in ([DONE], [FAILED], [GREEN], [RED])
       ) p
```